# Align vertically the elements of a column of a dataframe in R based on some character e.g. space

Tags: r, vertical-alignment, text-align

I want to align vertically the elements of a column in an R dataframe based on the last digit of the first element of each column.

How can I do that?

EDIT: Rephrasing: In R, using R code, I want to create code that will result as output in R console, will vertically align the left and right e.g. parentheses, depending on the longest in length column element, plus 1 extra space pad left/right before parentheses. See the below example:

Example df:

```
ugly_not_aligned_column <- structure(list(structure(c(2L, 13L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 10L, 3L, 12L, 1L, 14L, 4L, 11L), .Label = c("14 (55)", "20 (56)", "25.1 (72)", "2.79 (75)", "34.4 (97)", "9.29 (110)", "4.6 (125)", "55.36 (155)", "601 (170)", "65 (183)", "72 (205)", "7.29 (208)", "80 (224)", "806 (225)"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")

> EDIT: The arrangement of parenthesis are not aligned vertically in the last column because, the lenght of column elements differ e.g. 224 vs 56. 

1      20 (56)
2     80 (224)
3  55.36 (155)
4    4.6 (125)
5    601 (170)
6   9.29 (110)
7    34.4 (97)
8     65 (183)
9    25.1 (72)
10  7.29 (208)
11     14 (55)
12   806 (225)
13   2.79 (75)
14    72 (205)
```

EDIT: Example of parenthesis that are vertically aligned e.g. 20 has a shorter lenght form the column element 26.67, howevr, parenthesis are aligned vertically.

1 maybe  ( 46.67 )
2    no  ( 26.67 )
3   yes  ( 26.67 )
4 maybe  ( 13.33 )
5    no  ( 73.33 )
6   yes  ( 13.33 )
7 maybe  (    20 )
8    no  (    40 )
9   yes  (    40 )

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to do this for printing in the console? Or in markdown? Do you want to pad with spaces?

Comment: It would probably be easiest to split the column.

Comment: can you expaain me the difference between markdown and console? I want to be printed in console in a nice visual way as I described as well to be able to save it in csv file as such! @Roland, I dont want to split the column, it was created through paste0 command. Is there a way to manipulate paste0 command in order to produce a nicer visual printed result?

Comment: You could try `mx <- max(nchar(as.character(ugly_not_aligned_column[,1]))); format(as.character(ugly_not_aligned_column[,1]), width = mx, justify = 'left')`

Comment: Printing to the console is fundamentally different from exporting to a CSV. Alignment is usually a task for your text viewer or spreadsheet software. And you make the job for these easier if you have two columns. If you insist on doing this from R, you need to add spaces and that could create issues in your subsequent workflow.

Comment: @Roland, numbers will not be manipulated as such after a such process. However, you may have a right about other types of R command that may do not respect "spaces". Numbers will not be formatted as "characters" if space is added? this will not be the safety line for other R commands in order not to remove it?

Comment: @Roland, the alignment was done on the first digit of the first element of every row, while i want alignment on the last digit of the first elemnt of every row, vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: Edited based on comment.

This code adds trailing spaces, so all elements have the same length.

```
df <- structure(list(structure(c(2L, 13L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 10L, 3L, 12L, 1L, 14L, 4L, 11L), .Label = c("14 (55)", "20 (56)", "25.1 (72)", "2.79 (75)", "34.4 (97)", "9.29 (110)", "4.6 (125)", "55.36 (155)", "601 (170)", "65 (183)", "72 (205)", "7.29 (208)", "80 (224)", "806 (225)"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
colnames(df) = "text"
df %>% separate(text, c("number1", "number2"), " ")
```

Output of print(df):

```
   number1 number2
1       20    (56)
2       80   (224)
3    55.36   (155)
4      4.6   (125)
5      601   (170)
6     9.29   (110)
7     34.4    (97)
8       65   (183)
9     25.1    (72)
10    7.29   (208)
11      14    (55)
12     806   (225)
13    2.79    (75)
14      72   (205)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, but the alignment is based on the first digit of every row not the last digit of the first element of every row! Can be manipulated to produce a such result? I can manipulate it in paste0 command -before join them together in order to produce such result?

Comment: Edited with another suggestion. This is more visually pleasing than printing it as one separate column. I hope this is more in line with what you were hoping for.

Comment: yes, indeed Florian! Thank you! It is what asked for! However, not in a single column ;)

Comment: Although, If an answer is provided that this is done in a single column, it will be preferred

Comment: Hello. An important question. Stackoverflow tells me to "improve" my old questions". I find out that these question had received some unfavorable ranking... due to phrase wording or not stating the question very clear maybe. How can I improve that question?

Comment: @EliasEstatisticsEU Good of you to actually review your own older questions :) What you did well; you added a reproducible example with data that others can immediately use. What you could improve is make sure it is 100% clear what you want and how it should be aligned; ideally, you would also show others what exactly your expected output looks like. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an R Function in which when someone wants to join together two columns, and he / she wants the elements of the first column be aligned 
based on their last character / digit, then this R functions can do that.

However, this R function do something different from what asked for - to align the elements of a column when these elements were already joined from two different df columns. Nevertheless, I post  here the written R function for somone else that had a similar problem with me.

```
df <- list(structure(list(ID_no = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L), Variable = c("practice", "", "", "usefullness", "", "", 
    "stress", "", ""), Levels = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("female", "male", "maybe", "no", "yes"
    ), class = "factor"), Frequency = c(7, 4, 4, 2, 11, 2, 3, 6, 
    6), Percentage = c(46.67, 26.67, 26.67, 13.33, 73.33, 13.33, 
    20, 40, 40), y_place = c(76.5, 39.5, 13, 92.5, 49.5, 6.5, 90, 
    60, 20)), .Names = c("ID_no", "Variable", "Levels", "Frequency", 
    "Percentage", "y_place"), row.names = 3:11, class = "data.frame"))


   ID_no    Variable Levels Frequency Percentage y_place
3      2    practice  maybe         7      46.67    76.5
4      2                 no         4      26.67    39.5
5      2                yes         4      26.67    13.0
6      3 usefullness  maybe         2      13.33    92.5
7      3                 no        11      73.33    49.5
8      3                yes         2      13.33     6.5
9      4      stress  maybe         3      20.00    90.0
10     4                 no         6      40.00    60.0
11     4                yes         6      40.00    20.0


Aligned_Column_Join <- function(df, column_1, column_2) {

# Producing some spaces in order to make nice looking printed datasets
      df_col1      <- df[,column_1]
  count_chars      <- nchar(as.character(df_col1))
    max_count      <- max( count_chars )
       spaces      <- unlist( lapply( max_count - count_chars, function(x) paste0(if (x==0) { "" } else { rep(" ", x) }, collapse="") ))
df_aligned_col1    <- paste0( spaces, df_col1 ) 

     df_col2       <- df[,column_2]
  count_chars      <- nchar(as.character(df_col2))
    max_count      <- max( count_chars )
       spaces      <- unlist(lapply( max_count - count_chars, function(x) paste0(if (x==0) { "" } else { rep(" ", x) }, collapse="") ) )
df_aligned_col2    <- paste0(spaces, df_col2 ) 


    # Frequency and percentage columns made together
    aligned_elements <-    unname(as.data.frame(
                           paste(df_aligned_col1, " (",  
                           df_aligned_col2, ")" ))) 


    aligned_elements
}
```

command:

```
Aligned_Column_Join(df,3,5)
```

Output:

```
1 maybe  ( 46.67 )
2    no  ( 26.67 )
3   yes  ( 26.67 )
4 maybe  ( 13.33 )
5    no  ( 73.33 )
6   yes  ( 13.33 )
7 maybe  (    20 )
8    no  (    40 )
9   yes  (    40 )
```

command:

```
Aligned_Column_Join(df,4,5)
```

Output:

```
1  7  ( 46.67 )
2  4  ( 26.67 )
3  4  ( 26.67 )
4  2  ( 13.33 )
5 11  ( 73.33 )
6  2  ( 13.33 )
7  3  (    20 )
8  6  (    40 )
9  6  (    40 )
```